# Botão de compartilhar com contagem de shares

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, twitter-api, google-plus

Olá,

Gostaria de colocar no meu site botões de compartilhamento para facebook, twitter e google+. Mas gostaria de usar um visual customizado para os botões, mas sendo assim, não sei como aplicar o número de contagem de shares para cada vez que a página for compartilhada. É possível?

Comment: Se entendi corretamente é possível sim. Nos conte o que você já tentou. Obteve algum erro? Se possível, mostre um trecho do código que você fez.

Comment: Na verdade eu fiz os 3 botões, com css customizado. Usei apenas urls específicas para compartilhar em cada rede social. Mas assim, eles não trazem a contagem de compartilhamentos. Acredito que para isso, precisa ser usado javascript ou talvez a API oficial. Lendo a documentação oficial do facebook, por exemplo, eu não entendi como usar os botões que eles fornecem, mostrar a contagem de compartilhamentos, e aplicar meu próprio estilo.